# Defining multi-module dependency using custom configuration in Gradle does not trigger required tasks

Tags: gradle

I have two modules in my Gradle project:

- `ts` containing single page app sources
- `edge` containing Java sources which will serve said SPA

I have managed to integrate Yarn build with Gradle so that executing `gradle :ts:assemble` will produce single zip file with compiled js files and also including that archive in the final JAR via `gradle :edge:processResources` using custom configuration that expects zip files. Everything works fine if I just manually invoke `gradle :ts:assemble :edge:processResources` however if I try `gradle :edge:processResources` the build will fail immediately with File not found error. Somehow Gradle doesn't know that it should assemble `ts` project before processing resources of `edge`

**ts/build.gradle**

```
configurations {
  create("default")
}

artifacts {
  add("default", assemble) {
    name = project.name
    version = project.version
    classifier = extension
  }
}

//Yarn tasks omitted for brevity
```

**edge/build.gradle**

```
configurations {
  bundle
}

dependencies {
  bundle project(":ts")
  //other dependencies
}

processResources {
  configurations.bundle.files.each { bundle ->
    from zipTree(bundle)
    into "public"
  }
}
```